# Thread Terminating Early with Code 255

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I'm attempting to run a part of my program in a thread and getting an unusual result.

I have updated this question with the results of the [changes suggested by Remus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670450/thread-terminating-early-with-code-255/6670885#6670885), but as I am still getting an error, I feel the question is still open.

I have implemented functionality in a dll to tie into a piece of vendor software.  Everything works until I attempt to create a thread inside this dll.

Here is the relevant section of the DLL:

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl ccEntryOnEvent(WORD event);
}
```

to define the function the vendor's software calls, then:

```
using namespace std;

HANDLE LEETT_Thread = NULL;
static bool run_LEETT = true;
unsigned threadID;
void *lpParam;

int RunLEETTThread ( void ) {
    LEETT_Thread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, LEETT_Main, lpParam, 0 , &threadID );
    //LEETT_Thread = CreateThread ( NULL, 0, LEETT_Main, lpParam, 0 , NULL );

    if ( LEETT_Thread == NULL ) 
        ErrorExit ( _T("Unable to start translator thread") );

    run_LEETT = false;  // We only wish to create the thread a single time.
    return 0;
}

extern "C" void __cdecl ccEntryOnEvent(WORD event ) {
    switch (event) {
    case E_START:
        if ( run_LEETT ) {
            RunLEETTThread ();
            MessageText ( "Running LEETT Thread" );
        }
        break;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject( LEETT_Thread ,INFINITE);
    return;
}
```

The function is declared as

```
unsigned __stdcall LEETT_Main ( void* lpParam ) {
```

LEETT_Main is about 136k when compiled as a stand alone executable with no optimization (I have a separate file with a main() in it that calls the same function as myFunc).

Prior to changing the way the thread is called, the program would crash when declaring a structure containing a std::list, shown here:

```
struct stateFlags {
    bool inComment;    // multiline comments bypass parsing, but not line numbering
    // Line preconditions
    bool MCodeSeen;  // only 1 m code per block allowed
    bool GCodeSeen;  // only 1 g code per block allowed

    std::list <int> gotos; // a list of the destination line numbers
};
```

It now crashes on the _beginthreadex command, tracing through shows this

```
    /*
     * Allocate and initialize a per-thread data structure for the to-
     * be-created thread.
     */
    if ( (ptd = (_ptiddata)_calloc_crt(1, sizeof(struct _tiddata))) == NULL )
            goto error_return;
```

Tracing through this I saw a error 252 (bad ptr) and ultimately 255 (runtime error).

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this sort of behaviour creating threads (in dlls?) and what the remedy might be.  When I create an instance of this structure in my toy program, there was no issue.  When I removed the list variable the program simply crashed elsewhere, on the declaration of a string

I'm very open to suggestions at this point, if I have to I'll remove the idea of threading for now, though it's not particularly practical.

Thanks, especially to those reading this over again :)

Comment: Could this be a runtime conflict between the calling application and your DLL.  Have you ensured that you're using the same runtime?  There are potential problems when mixing /MT /MTd /MD and /MDd.

Comment: @Stephen, just to rule this out - you say you're creating the thread on startup. Does your startup happen to be DllMain?

Comment: @Chad I am using their project configuration file, which uses /MT.  Additionally other projects I've developed in this environment execute correctly.

Comment: Have you tried without removing the std::list<> from your structure.  I realize this likely means you have to change some functionality -- this is really just a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Chad I haven't yet since it does mean a fair amount of edits, but if nothing else presents itself, that's what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads that use CRT (and `std::list` implies CRT) need to be created with [_beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), as documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT)
>   should use the _beginthreadex and _endthreadex functions for thread
>   management rather than CreateThread and ExitThread;

Is not clear how you start your thread, but it appears that you're doing it in DllMain which is not recommended (see [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn't it?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/04/4731478.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll make these changes in the morning and see if it resolves things.

Comment: Either I have implemented your suggestions incorrectly, or it has not solved my problem.  Thanks for the idea, however.

Comment: You say now it crashes on the line that allocates the TLS storage (`__declspec(thread)`) in `_beginthreadex`? Can you run your program under a real debugger (ie. Windbg, not Visual Studio) and see if any sort of SEH exception occurs in the `_calloc_crt` call? Also, inspect `!teb` (see http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#12_thread) and see what is the declared stack size at the point of failure.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the problem was the linker switch ... which is infuriating in a supplied project ...  However, if I had simply fixed that problem, the issues you answered to would have certainly bitten me in the arse, thus accepted :-)  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In rechecking the comments here and the configuration of the project, the vendor supplied solution file uses /MTd for debug, but we are building a DLL, so I needed to use /MDd, which immediately compiles and runs correctly.

Sorry about the ridiculous head scratcher...